# How to return a single HTML line based on two tags and two classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to return just the second line below. So I'd like to select based on tags `td` and `span` and classes `right` and `cap`.

```
<td class="center small"><span class="cap" title="">WR</span></td>
<td class="right"><span class="cap">$13,000,000</span></td>
```

I've tried the following, because I need to select the exact match of `cap` and not other classes like `cap info`:

`salaries = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get('class') == ['cap'])`

but it still returns the two lines below, because (I think) the `td` tags and corresponding classes still differ (as seen above in the original html lines):

`<span class="cap" title="">WR</span>, <span class="cap">$13,000,000</span>,`

Comment: Figured it out... 
`salaries = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get('class') == ['cap'] and not tag.get('title') == '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`salaries = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get('class') == ['cap'] and not tag.get('title') == '')`